# New Questions and Page reload

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh, question-lists

When I am idle on Stack Overflow, I see an update of x recent questions were added.

After clicking, the questions load properly, but they do not reflect:

1. If any of them were already answered.
2. If any of the existing questions were answered in the idle time.

--

Also, as per Richards comment - 
It often happens that one lands in "has been deleted" page off an idle page that has loaded up new questions. Only after a full page reload, all the questions are updated with correct number of answers, votes and views.

--

I would like it if the page refreshes on clicking the load recent questions link so that the questions which were already answered will get highlighted with correct information.

Comment: @Sha I'm not sure thats 100% right, I often get to "has been deleted" pages off an idle page that has loaded up new questions

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The number of answers show for the question is based on what it was when the page loaded, not what it was when you clicked "x questions with new activity".  Brand new questions shown in this manor always are displayed as having zero answers, even if it was answered before you asynchronously loaded it.  You need to do a full page refresh to see such information.  This is all the same with votes too.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd... It does not show if a question is answered, how many answers were posted and even the views doesn't update. I can update the question with snapshot, if that can help to explain?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No, it doesn't work as the OP is requesting on the "active" tab.  Even the active tab doesn't update to reflect answers posted after the page is loaded and before the asynchronous update.  I virtually always use the "active" tab myself, and while this isn't terribly annoying, it does bother me every once in a while.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The answer count won't always be zero, but it will be whatever it was when the page was loaded, not what the count is when you asynchronously update the content.  That is the feature request.  That is unless this has been changed rather recently.

Comment: @Servy OK, blonde 15 moments. Understood now.

Comment: I figured out one more strange behavior, if there are more than 50 recent questions, and i hit the load recent questions link, All 50 questions + the old questions appear on the page. It really doesnt matter how many questions per page option you have selected. Result is a looooong page. Right now I have almost 500 questions on one single webpage.

Comment: @ajc Pretty sure that's by design.  (as is this, for that matter).  If you want to remove all of the content you no longer want then just do a full page refresh.

Comment: @Servy...I agree. But then the question is, Is it really a good design? And i completely cool with refreshing the page, that sure makes everything straight, But again, for a website if we have to refresh a page to get a required result, its not a good practice, right?

Comment: This has  been asked now in a clearer manner, closing as dupe.